# Any arbitrary collection of elements of a set is a set. True or False

Tags: set-theory

I was reading Jech's Set Theory book and there I came across the definition of a subset. 
 A set $U$ is a subset of $X$, if $\forall z( z \in U \implies z \in X)$.  I wanted to ask the above question, if we take any arbitrary collection of elements in a given set, can we call that collection a set? 
Later on, it is also written $X \times Y \subset PP(X \cup Y)$, so $X \times Y$ is a set. So I am also wondering if it is enough to show that a collection is contained in a set for it to be a set.

Comment: The words "collection" & "set"  & "class" are not part of the formal language of ZFC. You should practice putting statements & Q's into the formal language to clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If by "collection" you mean "definable collection", i.e. a class, then indeed this is the exact formulation of the Axiom of Separation/Subset/Restricted Comprehension/it has many names.

---

There is something to say about "collection" being a more abstract property that we, as people not living inside a specific universe of set theory, can form without requiring it to have a definition internal to that universe we're considering. But if you're just starting out, I prefer to not confuse you too much, and I'll just remark and say that there is more to this than immediately meets the eye *because* "collection" is not part of the *technical* jargon, but more of a natural-language term.

Comment: I must say I was also hesitant writing the word "collection", I just wanted to know if the "collections" we form while being an universe outside of set theory can be expressed by a first order formula.

Comment: Usually they do. Sometimes they don't. It takes practice, and the understanding that a book/professor that is trying to *teach* you something isn't going to trick you for no reason (is what I used to tell my students in the first class of the year).

Comment: Thank You for the help will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the axiom schema of specification which states that ,Given any set $A,$ there is a set $B$ such that, given any set $x$, $x$ is a member of $B$ if and only if $x$ is a member of $A$ and $P$  holds for $x$